# How to prove a set is open by finding a ball around each point

Tags: real-analysis

How can we show that the set $ U=\{(x,y) \text{is an element of } \mathbb{R^2}:x^2+4y^2<4\}$ is open by finding a ball around each point which is contained in U

This question has been asked before but not answered.

Comment: I really don't know how to start. Its just open to me as there is no equality at 4.

Comment: You should not think of sets as open just because they do not have equality as above. Try to construct a ball about an arbitrary point $z= (x,y)$ in $U$ for some radius $r$. If your choice of radius is good, then your ball will lie in $U$ which implies it is open. You should also draw picture it will help alot.

Comment: There's no equal.  That's good intuitive start. Formalize it. Consider that every point in the set will have some distance to "the equal".  Make ball around the point that is smaller than the distance.

Comment: First try it with $y^2$ in place of $4y^2$.  Then see what needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

For each point $(x_0,y_0)$ of $U$ we have $$x_0^2+4y_0^2=4-\epsilon$$for some $\epsilon>0$. Therefore $B_\epsilon(x_0,y_0)=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2|(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=\dfrac{\epsilon^2}{100}\}$ has been contained in $U$